# Javascript OnPostback

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a user control A that is sitting on a page alongside another user control B.

Control A has it's own functionality, which includes some controls that cause postbacks (drop downs, checkboxes, etc).

I control B.  I don't control A.

B needs to hide a button that exists in A.

In B, I have markup and script like so:

```
<body onload="OnPageLoad();">
...

  function OnPageLoad() {
    $("input[name$='btnInPartA']").hide();
...
```

This successfully hides the button in A when the page is loaded.

Whenever a postback is fired from A, then the button reappears.

How can I keep that button hidden?  I'd like to fire my javascript code every time a postback occurs, but I'm open to other ideas.

Here is the markup for part B:

```
<body onload="OnPageLoad();">
  <div id="divDonationExtensionFields">
    <div id="divSubmitButton">
      <input type="button" id="btnCZDonate" value="Donate Now" onclick="btnCZDonate_OnClick();" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function OnPageLoad() {
    alert("OnPageLoad fired!");
    $("input[name$='btnNext']").hide();
  }

  function btnCZDonate_OnClick() {
    //do whatever part A was going to do
    $("input[name$='btnNext']").click();
    //do some custom stuff after that
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Is the `OnPageLoad` function called when the page reloads? Normally it should be called because you placed it in the `onload` attribute of the body, unless you are doing a partial postback (AJAX).

Comment: Have you noticed the contradiction? You don't control A but you want to control A. Let A control it's buttons. If something in B caused the postback you should use events to inform A. Then A can hide this button in that event itself.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I guess what he means is that he cannot hide the control on the server side because he has no control over the source code of control A. That's why he is using javascript in order to manipulate the markup generated by this control and achieve the desired effect.

Comment: @Tim and Darin: I'm trying to customize the behavior of a control that is handled by another team in my company.  Basically B has a new button that replaces the button on A.  So I hide A's button, and I need it to stay hidden across postbacks.

Comment: Yeah, we got that. What about my first question? Is the OnPageLoad function called when the page reloads?

Comment: @Darin: OnPageLoad is called when the page is rendered, or when you reload it (ie click the Refresh button) but not when postbacks from within the page occur.  So A's button is hidden until you check a box, or even if you click a button on B but, say, validation fails.

Comment: Since you placed it inside the `onload` handler it should be called when the page reloads. Or maybe the page doesn't reload at all because you are using AJAX? Is this the case?

Comment: I'm not using AJAX, although part A may be - I'm not too sure of all of it's internal workings.  It is likely that they swallow the postbacks with UpdatePanels.  In any case, my OnPageLoad() is definitely not called when postbacks from within either control occur.

Comment: Alright, but you could very easily see this in the Net tab of FireBug or Chrome Developer toolbar. What makes the button reappear again? Is it because the page got reloaded? What if you put your code in a $(document).ready callback?

Comment: Do you use UpdatePanel? - if yes then the onload is not run this way after the update panel is Update the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `pageLoad` special function instead of subscribing to the `onload` handler. The difference is that `pageLoad` will be invoked on every postback no matter if it is partial or not. It seems that there's some partial postback being done which is re-showing the button you have hidden and your `onload` function won't be invoked in this case:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function pageLoad() {
            alert("OnPageLoad fired!");
            $("input[name$='btnNext']").hide();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
```

You can read more about `pageLoad` and the difference with `$(document).ready` (or `onload`) in [`this article`](http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/).

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thanks for the help, and for the links.  I learned something new today.